# How can i keep listening to a websocket in a chrome packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

Currently when a background process always becomes inactive, even when i'm waiting for data from a websocket. Is there a way to circumvent this? The documentation is not clear at all in this department (old documentation etc.). What is the 'new' and correct way to do this?

My manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Media 5",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Html5 media center app for Chrome",
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "small_icon.png", "128": "big_icon.png"     },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["sandbox.html"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "fullscreen",
    "notifications", 
    "webview"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Will you please post your manifest so we can tell whether you're asking about a packaged app or a v2 app?

Comment: I changed my question and added the manifest file.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of ways to prevent your event page from getting unloaded, including those listed here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html. Give one of those a try. Open a message port, or set a chrome.alarms alarm for about a 5-second interval. I don't believe it's documented behavior, but event pages are typically unloaded after 10 seconds of inactivity, so the alarm ought to keep you alive.

I've filed [a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=204573) about this; it might be smarter for us to avoid unloading if you're using websockets.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that keeps packaged apps alive is having an active callback. So, for example, you could use setTimeout with a timeout value of say 5 to ensure you app remains alive. This is only a workaround though, and there should be a better way to reconcile lifetime of websockets and packaged apps.

There is a Chromium bug (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=204573) tracking this issue.

As an FYI (because this is confusing), the "persistent": true line is currently ignored by Chrome. Packaged Apps (v2) are always set to "persistent": false.